# Issues with Share button on Facebook Fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

My friend has created about 20 posts on the Facebook fan page for the website. www.AvailDiscounts.com

Now the issue is, when we click on the wall post(posted using RSS graffiti) to "share" button, its taking to another page where it displays the meta tags and the title of the login page of my site instead of displaying the exact post.

Please note that the feeds are shared using Feedburner and posted using RSS graffiti.

Please find the fan page of the website:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Avail-Discounts-Chicago/195486540483072

How to overcome this issue.

Any alternative method available?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to review how to use the [metadata](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) and you may also need to create your own RSS feed. If you go through the network timeline the links do pass through your login page, I am not really sure what data you are trying to send to the xd receiver.

There is a 301 Redirect in there which is what the Facebook Share button has noticed.